# Is the max matrix norm induced?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $\|A \| = \max_{1 \le i,j \le n} |a_{ij}|$, where $A$ is a square matrix. I can prove that this is a matrix norm, but is it an induced norm?

Answer (score 5):

No. It's not an induced norm. Let $\|\cdot \|$ be your norm. If it were is an induced norm then you'd have $\|A ^2 \| \leq \|A\| ^ 2$ for every matrix $A$. But consider  $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ to get $2 = \|A ^2 \| \nleq \|A\| ^ 2 = 1^2 = 1$. Thus, your norm can't be an induced one.

Comment: Actually, according to the definition of matrix norms, the inequality $\|A B \| \leq \|A\| \|B\|$ should hold for all matrices A and B (it's the fifth property in the definition), but since it doesn't hold for your counter example, then we don't even have a norm here, let alone an induced one. Am I correct?

Comment: @elkoldo In some contexts you require norms to be sub-multiplicative, but not always. Viewing the matrix as a chopped and stacked vector, you can define a matrix norm using a vector one.